Cannot visualize Orange's distributions
When attaching a Distributions widget to a Data Table widget, that was previously fed by a 8-column csv file, I don't see any histograms, whatever the feature being chosen.
I attach Orange's workflow below:

I attach the Distributions widget configuration below:

I even attach the select column widget configuration:

Where is the mistake?
